# Performance of DataWeave object constructor curly braces vs. evaluation parenthese in mapping functions

Tags: performance, object, mule, dataweave, mulesoft

What is the performance difference of using object constructor curly braces vs. evaluation parentheses in a mapping function? For example:

```
1 to 100 map {
    ($$): $
}
```

vs.

```
1 to 100 map (
    ($$): $
)
```

Comment: Have you tried running a benchmark to compare both?

Answer (score 2):

Both are semantically the same. And the execution is exactly the same. But just to clarify the syntax

```
1 to 100 map {
 ($$): $
}
```

This is exactly the same as

```
1 to 100 map ({
 ($$): $
})
```

It is wrapping the lambda body into parenthesis. Now for the non curly braces  case, DW supports what is called single key value pair objects. This mean that if your object has just one key then it is not needed to add {}. But this is a sugar syntax and nothing more. This is executed the same as the other node.

Hope it clarifies